# one selector gets all elements, but the other doesn't get all elements on the page

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, web-scraping

(modified after the advice from the comments)

*What I'm trying to do*: Web scraping to get all 100 cryptocurrency names from [this website](https://coinmarketcap.com/).

*Problem*: The selector I used doesn't select all crypto names on the page. Only some of them are selected.

In that webpage, there are 100 rows, and each row has one cryptocurrency name. So 100 names in total.

If I use this selector `tr td a[href*="/currencies/"][href$="/"]:not([href$="/markets/"])`,

It finds all 100 elements on the page, and I can get each crypto's URL from these 100 elements. (there are 100 cryptocurrencies on one page)

one sample of the selected 100 elements:

```
<a href="/currencies/ethereum/" class="cmc-link"><div class="sc-16r8icm-0 sc-1teo54s-0 dBKWCw"><img class="coin-logo" src="https://s2.coinmarketcap.com/static/img/coins/64x64/1027.png" loading="lazy" alt="ETH logo"><div class="sc-16r8icm-0 sc-1teo54s-1 dNOTPP"><p font-weight="semibold" color="text" font-size="1" class="sc-1eb5slv-0 iworPT">Ethereum</p><div class="sc-1teo54s-2 fZIJcI"><div class="sc-1teo54s-3 etWhyV">2</div><p color="text3" class="sc-1eb5slv-0 gGIpIK coin-item-symbol" font-size="1">ETH</p></div></div></div></a>
```

-No problem so far.

*But,* if I add `>div>div>p` to this selector to get each crypto name,

( `tr td a[href*="/currencies/"][href$="/"]:not([href$="/markets/"])>div>div>p` ),

only 19 elements are selected, not all 100 elements.

one sample of the selected elements:

```
<p font-weight="semibold" color="text" font-size="1" class="sc-1eb5slv-0 iworPT">Ethereum</p>
```

If I scroll down the page, the number of selected elements gets increased, but what I want is to get all 100 elements without wheel scrolling.

1. why the first selector finds the whole elements right away, while the second one needs to scroll down the page?
2. What selector should I use to select all 100 names of cryptocurrencies without scrolling down?

Thanks in advance :)

(I'm trying web scraping using Playwright, but I think this is just a general question on CSS selector)

Comment: _"If I scroll down the page, the number of selected elements gets increased"_ - So they are only added to the DOM when you scroll to them. Should be easy to verify.

Comment: @Andreas you're right. The selectors I used had no fault, they just did their work correctly. Thanks for your comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't a problem with css selectors. It's a dynamically loaded page so to get its contents you need to make an API call to

```
https://api.coinmarketcap.com/data-api/v3/map/all?listing_status=active,untracked&exchangeAux=is_active,status&cryptoAux=is_active,status&start=10001&limit=10000
```

Once you do that, you get back a json. To extract from that the currency code, for example, you need to

```
const obj = JSON.parse(response);
curs = obj['data']['cryptoCurrencyMap']
```

if you run

```
for (let cur of curs)
   {console.log(cur['symbol'])}
```

You should get quite a few codes...

Comment: Thanks, that's a much better way. I'm trying to create a map between coins' name(from the API) and their URL. i.e. {"Bitcoin": "https:.../bitcoin/", "Ethereum": "https..."}. Could you give me a hint on what to do? I don't think the API gives each coin's URL (But I successfully gathered the URLs from the webpage).

Comment: @starriet The coins' URLs are indeed not in the response. It's hard to answer in the abstract, but to do what you want, you'll need the coin names in one array, the URLs in another and then use `map()` on them. You may also post it as a separate question using as a sample an array w/3-4 coin names and another w/ their respective URLs.

Comment: Somehow I managed to do it, thanks!

Comment: @starriet Glad to hear!